# Conversion types in Python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, dictionary

I have the following code

```
text_file = open("up2017.txt", "r")
amount=[]
for line in text_file:

    fields =  line.strip().split(" ")
    amount.append(fields[-1])

list(map(float,amount))
```

And I get the following error

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '50.000,00'

The text files looks like

```
13.10    Ovf           12.10            50.000,00                50.000,00
30.10    Bgs                              30.10            12.000,00                62.000,00
30.11    Bgs                              30.11            12.000,00                74.000,00
15.12    Bgs                              15.12            53.528,36               127.528,36
30.12    Bgs                             30.12            12.000,00               139.528,36
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `str.replace` method:

```
amount.append(fields[-1].replace('.', '').replace(',', '.'))
```

Answer (score 3):

The correct way to do this is to use the appropriate `locale`.

For instance, on Spanish speaking countries it is very common to use `.` as the thousands separator and `,` as the decimal separator.

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, 'es')
value = locale.atof('50.032,56') # yields float(50032.56)
```

In your case, you can do something like:

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, 'es')

# ...

values = map(locale.atof, amount)
```